# How to kill a stuck print job under AIX?

Tags: printing, aix

```
0:root@SERVER:/ # uname
AIX
0:root@SERVER:/ # oslevel
6.1.0.0
0:root@SERVER:/ # switch.prt -d
#printsubsystem
AIX
0:root@SERVER:/ # lpstat -oQUEUENAME 
Queue   Dev   Status    Job Files              User         PP %   Blks  Cp Rnk
------- ----- --------- --- ------------------ ---------- ---- -- ----- --- ---
QUEUENA QUEUE READY    
QUEUENAME: 
QUEUENAME:                          Windows LPD Server
QUEUENAME:                               Printer \\192.168.2.34\QUEUENAME
QUEUENAME: 
QUEUENAME: Owner       Status         Jobname          Job-Id    Size   Pages  Priority
QUEUENAME: ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
QUEUENAME: A22adm (10. Waiting   02bT7zBL.A22          1703      3374      0      1
0:root@SERVER:/ # cancel 1703 QUEUENAME           
0:root@SERVER:/ #                        
0:root@SERVER:/ # lpstat -oQUEUENAME   
Queue   Dev   Status    Job Files              User         PP %   Blks  Cp Rnk
------- ----- --------- --- ------------------ ---------- ---- -- ----- --- ---
QUEUENA QUEUE READY    
QUEUENAME: 
QUEUENAME:                          Windows LPD Server
QUEUENAME:                               Printer \\192.168.2.34\QUEUENAME
QUEUENAME: 
QUEUENAME: Owner       Status         Jobname          Job-Id    Size   Pages  Priority
QUEUENAME: ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
QUEUENAME: A22adm (10. Waiting   02bT7zBL.A22          1703      3374      0      1
0:root@SERVER:/ #
```

I also tried to:

```
stopsrc -g spooler
startsrc -g spooler
```

and

```
disable QUEUENAME
enable QUEUENAME
```

and

```
/usr/bin/enq -P 'QUEUENAME' -x '1703'
```

and tried removing the print job with smitty, but with no luck..

any help?

Comment: What are you using to use the Windows Print Queue?

Answer (score 1):

`lpstat -o` may not be showing all digits of the print job number.

To show full info:

```
qchk -L -P PrintQ
```